# How is it possible to detect a single photon?

Tags: photons, quantum-information

I'm trying to understand conceptually what does it mean to detect a single photon, how is that possible? how do we make sure it's exactly one photon and not more? what about the photon statistics?
what about the single-photon source? How can we obtain SINGLE photon? what is the definition of single photon?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Focusing on a single question makes easier to answer

Answer (score 0):

A simple Geiger counter will do, and an x-ray or gamma source. The statistics will be like a Poisson distribution. You would probably recognize the sound.

Comment: Given the tagging the OP is probably interested in provable single-photon detection (whether they know it or not) which is a little more complicated than single-photon senstivity.